# multi flow navigation UI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to develop multi flow navigation using Shell & SplitApp controls.

I'm able to create shell and splitapp controls individually now I'm trying to provide navigation between shell and splitapp.

So the flow would be:

1. login View
2. Dashboard.
3. master details views

---

I'm using component.js for loading components and providing routing.
With this structure I'm able to navigate from master page to navigate page but **I was struck at structuring the application.**

I tried googling but didn't find anything useful.

I've followed the ui5 TDG for structuring the application.
[UI5-TDG](https://github.com/j1wu/sapui5-app-tdg)

**Below is the sample image of dashboard view**
[image: Shell]

**Below is the sample image of master detail view**

[image: splitapp]

---

Am I the only one trying this kind of scenario or did I miss something?

Any suggestions/materials/resources on structuring of application would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Do you use the routing? [link] (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/688f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e.html).
This link show the "old" mode to use routing. In Openui5 1.28 there are the concept of "target".

Comment: @padibro Thanks for your comment. I do use routing in my app.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate in your app the first thing to do is create a correct routing in Component.js file.
In the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/688f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e.html) you can see a mode to define the routing. But this mode is @deprecated from 1.28

The right way to compose the routing json is using `routes` and `targets`. You can see an example downloading the SDK and navigating in

```
openui5-sdk-1.28.11\test-resources\sap\m\demokit\master-detail\src\Component.js
```

If you have in mind the flow of your app you know each screen; in your example you have 3 screen: login, dashboard and cart; moreover you know that cart have a master and detail page (products and product).

Start immediately with splitapp (although some screens not have master) and compose router in the Component.js; you have:

- 3 routes: login, dashboard and cart. Targets are respectively ["login_detail"], ["dashboard_detail"], ["products_master", "product_detail"]
- 4 target: login_detail, dashboard_detail, products_master, product_detail, one for each view.

Comment: then you can navigate using navTo function https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html#navTo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think using splitapp for all the screns instead I was thinking of using shell and splitapp. So I'm searching for multiflow navigatoin with splitapp and shell.